# XSLT: Avoid outputting remaining data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm currently working on an XSL Transform Script for some data migration but I'm having this problem.

I would have XML files with multiple nodes I need to access data from, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <a>
        <fname>James</fname>
        <lname>Reeves</lname>
    </a>
    <b>
        <fname>Tim</fname>
        <lname>Stoddard</lname>
    </b>
</note>
```

However I only want the transformed XML to output the data from node **a** and not **b**, so typically I would write this XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="a">
    <name first="{fname}" last="{lname}"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
<name last="Reeves" first="James"/>TimStoddard
```

With this example, I could change the template match to **b**, which would get this output:

```
JamesReeves<name last="Stoddard" first="Tim"/>
```

So Is there a way to stop the XSLT from outputting any remaining data not set in a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to suppressing the output, you can make sure you select only those elements for processing that interest you:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//a"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Depending on your output needs you might want to create a root element e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//a"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, didn't realize I could use // to apply elements from root!

Comment: You should not use //, if you can avoid it (very bad for the performance). Use <xsl:apply-templates select="/note/a"/> or an empty template matching on the element b to delete it.

Comment: @NicoKutscherauer, are you talking about a particular implementation where `//` is "very bad for the performance"? With XPath 1.0 dating from 1999 and XPath 2.0 from 2007 these days implementations have matured and optimizing `//foo` is something considered first due to its ubiquitous use.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the default copying of text by matching `text()` and not outputting anything:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

If you also want to suppress the default copying of attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*"/>
```

Comment: That works with text, however it still leaves any text that is numerical. For example: 2014-04-09 16:21:58.0002014-04-09 16:22:30.0002014-04-09 16:22:41.000
I tried adding a similar template using "number()" but that threw an error. is there something similar for numbers?

Comment: Sounds like you might also want to suppress attributes by default, then.  (It's not text vs numeric that would matter here; it'd have to be text in elements vs text in attribute values.)  See updated answer.